# How can I express \begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2ex}?

Tags: minipage, width

I am working on a poster template with a not so easy to reproduce style with nested blocks. To that end, I have to create a minipage whose width depends on `\linewidth` minus some fixed value. In a nutshell, I want to subtract something in the width specification of the minipage.

How can I express `\linewidth "MINUS" 2ex` in my template?

Comment: Just load the `calc` package and use `\linewidth-2ex`; you probably mean `-2em`, though.

Comment: Or precede it with `\dimexpr`: `\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2ex}`

Comment: @egreg: I didn't know about the `calc` package. This answers the question (*hint*). (Note: I did mean `2ex` since it is determined by a different vertical margin.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `calc` package allows for expressing operations on dimensions in the argument to `minipage`, `\parbox`, `\setlength` and other places.

So, after `\usepackage{calc}`, you're allowed to say

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2ex}
```

Without any package the same can be accomplished by

```
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2ex\relax}
```

but `calc` is more powerful.